# Can anyone provide me the PHP library for salesforce oauth2.0 REST API?

Tags: php, cakephp, rest, oauth, salesforce

Right now m developing a web app which acts as a consumer for http://salesforce.com but I am unable to make a controller for the API implementation.

Can anyone provide me the php library for salesforce oauth2.0 REST API...?

Comment: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php (first google hit)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently Open Sourced a Cakephp 2.x datasource I have created to interact with Salesforce Enterprise - not sure if its suitable for what you want as you havent specified whether you are using a framework or not but take a look:

[CakePHP Salesforce Enterprise Datasource](https://github.com/voycey/Salesforce-Enterprise-API-CakePHP-2.x-Plugin)

This uses the developerforce PHP toolkit as mentioned in some other posts but simplifies a whole lot of things!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything official, but you can take a look at the Salesforce REST API client used in Workbench (PHP-based app) to get you started:

http://code.google.com/p/forceworkbench/source/browse/trunk/workbench/restclient/RestClient.php